# Showing Keyboard with Android Dialog

Tags: android, user-interface, user-input

I want to show the Android version of a [Model Dialog](http://bit.ly/dc3pXu) with text input however I think the keyboard will be behind the actual activity since dialogs weren't made to have inputs. Is there any way I can get the keyboard to show in an actual dialog.

I did see [this](http://bit.ly/aqgpOL) SO question -- however I'd rather not use an Theme.Dialog'ed activity because I feel like an activity would be too heavy for my purposes. How can I show this Model Dialog with the keyboard input in the foreground?

This is what I am talking about:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Who said dialogs aren't made to have inputs?! A dialog can contain anything - text, buttons, progress bars, input fields. Did you try it out? A keyboard resizes your canvas, so there's no "behind"/"front" going on. (Besides, you can always summon the IME on a phone without a QWERTY 
keyboard by holding the menu button - even there's a modAl dialog.)

EDIT: If you need proof, just look at the API Demos (App -> Dialog). There's an example for a dialog with text entry. Source code here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/AlertDialogSamples.html (DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY)

Comment: I updated my previous question with a picture that shows where I saw this.

Comment: Well, yeah, that's a system dialog about the IME. But your app won't look like that. Look at the API Demos in the Google SDK - Check out App -> Dialog -> Text Entry dialog. There's a simple example for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you link me or post the code in your answer -- I don't see the file you are talking about. 

Also if you post the code in your answer it will benefit others.

Comment: The API demos are on your local hard disk. You got them when you installed the SDK. I'll edit the answer for more details.

Comment: Thanks -- I saw that. Exactly the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: What exactly do you mean there's no "behind/front" going on, because in my case the keyboard keeps appearing for some reason behind my dialog, that means I broke the whole android system?